# what does the output "<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000020B9232B888>" mean in python-3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

code:

```
marks = [[ input() , float(input()) ] for _ in range(int(input()))]

s = ( y for [x,y] in marks)

print(s)

l = list(s)
l.sort() 

print(l)

sec = l[1]
ans = [x for [x,y] in marks if y == sec]

ans.sort()
for x in ans:
print(x)
```

output:

```
5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39

<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000020B9232B888>

[37.2, 37.21, 37.21, 39.0, 41.0]
Berry
Harry
```

Comment: That's the string representation of a generator object. You need to iterate the generator to get values out of it.

Comment: Here is some reading to understand generators: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python

Comment: Your use of parentheses for the comprehension that you stored in s results in a generator object.  If you'd used square brackets, it would have resulted in the list that your later list(s) call makes.  So, you can combine those lines by changing the parentheses to square brackets.